# Regex to make a word camel case in alpine linux

Tags: regex, sed, alpine-linux

I have tried this regex in centos

**RegEx**: `echo 'select-value'|sed -r 's/(-)(\w)/\U\2/g'`

**Output**: `selectValue`

But in alpine i am not getting the output when i tried the below regex

**RegEx**: `echo 'select-value'|sed -r 's/(-)(\w)/\%U\2/g'`

**Output**: `select%Uvalue`

**Expected Output**: `selectValue`

Please suggest the right regex.

Thanks

Comment: Have you placed the `%` in the second `sed` command on purpose or is it a typo?

Comment: That is purposefully done. According to this documentation. https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Regex

Comment: What is the output of the first regex in alpine linux?

Comment: Output for echo 'select-value'|sed -r 's/(-)(\w)/\U\2/g' this in alpine is selectUvalue

Comment: `echo 'select-value'|sed -r 's/(-)(\w)/\U\2/g'` does not work correctly in alpine?

Comment: What version of alpine and sed are you using?

Comment: My alpine version is  3.5.2

Comment: Where do you see `\%U` on that regex page you linked?

Comment: Do you know why you are using Alpine?

Comment: https://thenewstack.io/alpine-linux-heart-docker/

Comment: I think it works in GNU Sed as [Master_ex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/854980/master-ex) mentioned  @[UnbearableLightness](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3390419/unbearablelightness)

Comment: Don't trust that guy (in the article you posted). Alpine Linux is coming from embedded systems where size is *really* critical. Some crazy Docker folks nowadays think that size (a very few MB of diskspace and network traffic) matters so much that they are willing to accept the craziest scripting headaches from the 1980s for that. (Plus the fun to require programs to work with musl instead of glibc). Use small GNU/Linux based container images if you want to create something which is fun instead of a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that alpine uses the busybox sed by default. You have to install the gnu sed (it may be already installed).

In a docker alpine 3.5 container I've tried that one and it worked `echo 'select-value'|/bin/sed -r 's/(-)(\w)/\U\2/g'`. Mind the `/bin/sed` part. Gnu sed was already installed in the docker image.

If you have not luck with that you may use `awk` if available:

```
echo 'select-value-another-value'|awk -F'-' '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2);printf "\n"}'
```

Comment: I have busybox sed in my image, not Gnu. The second one works for me. 
Thanks a lot [Master_ex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/854980/master-ex)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't *have* to use sed, try perl:

```
$ echo 'select-value-but-not-that-one'|perl -pe 's/-(\w)/\u$1/g'
selectValueButNotThatOne
```

Comment: I have only sed(stream editor) in my alpine utility but not Perl :-(